# How to update updateble ResultSet with SQL Function e.g. NOW()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

Is there any way to call SQL Function during updateXXX method in ResultSet of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE.

For example look at this code fragment:

```
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
  rs.updateTimestamp("status_time", "NOW()"); // call some SQL function during update
  rs.updateRow();
}
```

Is there any way to update value such way? The above example ofcourse don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. These methods are for setting actual values, not for executing SQL functions.